# %Like% on spring boot with entity manager

Tags: java

How to solve this on jpa query on spring boot? I have error implement this query

```
@Override
public List<Artikel> find(String judul) {
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    return em.createQuery("from Artikel where judul like %:'"+judul+"'%",    Artikel.class).getResultList();
}
```

Can you help me please to solve it?
I want it, implement with entity manager, WITHOUT REPOSITORY

Comment: without which repository?

Comment: Be careful with concatenation -- if you use user supplied data, you will have SQL-injection.

Comment: so, how can do this?